# android layout pushing views from the screen

Tags: android, xml, layout, view

For building an application, we have several lists. 
the problem exists with a list item, which is custom, but very simple nontheless.
The format is:

[image]

This represents one list item with 2 textviews and one image view

Note that title and date are actually right underneath eachother and the image is on the right side, with center vertical as attribute.**The image should NOT be in between the two text views**

I will give the XML first and then explain the exact problem.

**The XML:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView 
            android:textSize="16dip" 
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView 
            android:textSize="12dip" 
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/validationStateImg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Problem:**
In some sense, this layout displays everything exactly as the ascii representation.
What does NOT function correctly is when the text is becoming long. In cases where the text is long, but not long enough to take 2 lines, it just makes the imageview tiny.

In other cases, it just pushes imageview completely off the screen..

What I need is, when the length of either the date or the other textview is too long, to break to a new line. And ofcourse it needs to be a solution portable to all sorts of screen sizes.

I'm not a UI artist, so, apologies if I'm abusing layouts in a sense that they should not be used.

Aside help, tips and hints are also welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your best bet is one simple RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/validationStateImg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/validationStateImg"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/validationStateImg"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Snap the ImageView to the right side of the parent, and let the TextViews take the rest of the width, but aligned to the left of the ImageView.

Comment: Altough I just got a reply that solved my problem, Im curious about this one. Atleast for the learning curve. Will this also make sure text does NOT push out the image if the text is too big?

Comment: Yeah, this method will give the image the priority of size. The ImageView will be just wide enough to contain the image at 100% (so keep in mind if you throw a *very* large image in there your layout you're going to get some ugly results), and it will fill the rest of the RelativeLayout vertically. The gravity attribute will make the image stay in the vertical center of the ImageView. Only after the ImageView is placed will the TextViews be placed. Then they'll expand to fill the leftover space, taking multiple lines if necessary, but never overlapping the image.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Very clear. Learned somethign new today. This is very elegant, with only one layout, perfect alignments. Thanks alot.

Comment: http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/03/01/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-part-1/ from google engineer. The article is quite a gift.

Comment: @Avinazz Every time I see a curious-creature.org link, I know it's going to be worthwhile. :)

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight = "1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="dasdfasdfasdfasdfsadfsdf dsfasdfasd asdfadsf dfasdfads asdfasdf"
        android:textSize="16dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="dasdfasdfasdfasdfsadfsdf"
        android:textSize="12dip" />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/validationStateImg"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have not optimized the layout though. You can use single relative layout and get a desired layout too.

Comment: Did my solution helped? Any problem let us know with more elaboration.

Comment: kcoppock's solution is optimized one.

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case you need a different layout, check this one:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView 
           android:textSize="16dip" 
           android:id="@+id/title"
           android:layout_width="match_parent" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView 
           android:textSize="12dip" 
           android:id="@+id/date"
           android:layout_width="match_parent" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/validationStateImg"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This example is not what I am looking for. If only i wanted the three items to be underneath eachother. the 2 texts should be underneath eachother, the image on the right of those 2 texts, vertical_center aligned.

Comment: @Joey Roosing oh i see now, this image example is much better, i'v updated my answer with new XML

Comment: thanks alot. Im working on trying this one out. Getting some inflating errors using this though. Trying to sort them out.

Comment: @Joey Roosing there was typo error `LineareLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`, is fixed now.

Comment: I got it working. Didn't see the typo. Compiler wasn't complaining either. This solution does exactly what I want it to do now. Could you please explain the role of width="0dp" compared to wrap_content? Aside from that part, I understand the differences. It works, thanks alot :)

Comment: You're welcome, width="0dp" must be used with `weight` attribute in linear layout to show that this layout would take as much place as possible for it own with. Check [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight) link to Android Docs, you would find all info about weights there)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your image shrinking then you need to give it a specific ratio of the real estate that its parent offers.

Specifically the LinearLayout that is its parent needs to have a weight_sum and then both the text and image need to have a layout_weight.

the weight should add up to the sum.  The weight doesn't have to be a whole number and it's very important (and very counter intuitive) that the layout_width needs to be 0 (assuming that the two of them are sitting side by side)... so...

I'm removing all the extra stuff below that you need to add back in and just leaving the important parts....

```
<LinearLayout weight_sum=2 layout_height=fill_parent>
   <TextView layout_weight=2 layout_height=0dp/>
   <ImageView layout_weight=2 layout_height=0dp />
   <TextView layout_weight=2 layout_height=0dp/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This will split the LinearLayout in half and the left side will be text (which will wrap if it can) and the right side will be the image.  You can adjust this by setting the sum to 3 and splitting up the sides to 2 and 1 in which case the text will be 2/3 of the screen and the image 1/3.  Or leave the sum at 2 and have the left be 1.3 and the right .7 for a similar effect.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. For your edit, a vertical layout will not do what I want. because the image should be next to both texts, not in between AND be vertical_center aligned. Will your answer still suffice? I havent tried it just yet. Im going to upload an image with what i need.